# Xcode/Obj-c - Segue pushes new instance

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I have seen similar questions a lot on Stackoverflow and I tried a lot of things but I can't seem to figure this out. I have multiple TableViewControllers and 1 MainViewController. The MainViewController has buttons calling the different TableViewControllers and on selecting a tablecell the tableViewController dismisses.

The problem is that im pushing a new instance of my MainViewController every time I push from either one of my tableViewControllers. I currently use Segues to push between these different controllers.

In short: When switching from TableViewControllers to ViewController I want to prevent the ViewController to get pushed as a new instance because this way its removing my previous data input.

Im pretty sure I have to use either:

```
[self dismissModalViewController: withCompletion:]
performSegue
prepareForSegue
```

Or set some global variables in a class and call those, but im not experienced enough yet to implement this correctly.

A simple example of end result would be: 3 textfields in VC. On clicking textfield1 it opens tableview1 and on clicking a cell it updates textfield1. Textfield2 opens tableview2, etc.

Hope im clear enough, could post sample code if needed.

Edit, posting code (keep in mind, segues are performed in storyboard):
TableViewExample.h:

```
@interface IndustryViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

NSArray *tableViewArray;}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewIndustry;
```

TableViewExample.m:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showIndustry"]) {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewIndustry indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.industryText = [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    destViewController.industryTextName = [tableViewArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}}
```

Then in ViewController.m, viewDidLoad:

```
 [industry setTitle:industryText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

These are the most important parts I think.

Comment: please post yor code .

Comment: What kind of Segue are you using? 'modal'?

Comment: Done, if you need more let me know.

Comment: @MikePollard : Well I tried multiple solutions, currently its modal/popover.

Comment: `prepareForSegue:` can be called many times ? If it is, you should move your lines : ` NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableViewIndustry indexPathForSelectedRow];
    ViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;` into the `viewDidLoad`, so it will be called only 1 time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the segue of type "Push"? If so you should try dismissing the table view controllers using:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

If the segue is of type "Modal" instead you should do something like this on your table view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // your logic here
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

As for the data exchange between controllers what I would personally do is creating a public property in the header file of the Table View Controller, like the following:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) <Your_UIViewController_Subclass_Here> *mainController
```

Than, in the main controller, override the prepareForSegue:sender: method to set the newly created property to point to the main controller, like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   <Your_Subclass_Of_UITableViewController_Here> *destinationController = segue.destinationController;
   destinationController.mainController = self;
}
```

Now the Table View Controller will have a pointer to the main controller to send the data basically all you have to do is to implement some public method or property in the Main Controller to be called when the user selects a table view row in the table view controller in order to update the text in the textfields or whatever data model you are using.

Comment: For a Push segue you need to use a Navigation Controller if im not mistaking, which im not using. So the segue is of type "modal"/"popover". Would it work if I used a Navigation Controller with Push segues?

Comment: Yes, if embedded in a navigation controller when the segue is performed the instance of the previous controller is preserved so when you pop the view controller that was segued you get the same controller that fired the segue. I think that even on modal you should  be able to do what you are trying to do but I almost use always push segues.

Comment: Ok let me know! Off course consider that you should find a way to pass the data from the pushed view controller to the previous view controller when you pop the controller that was segued, if you have not already done this.

Comment: I have already written that code, the problem was the segue pushing a new instance of my maincontroller, hope it works!

Comment: just updated the answer with a possible solution using modal segue

Comment: Ok so I made a new project and used a navigation controller. I got it all setup but in my previous project I used:(void)prepareForSegue (see my edited version above for full code) to send the data back to the viewcontroller. I dont think I should use this method if I dismiss the viewcontroller through code so how do I update the fields now? I hope im clear enough.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, just updated the answer with a possible solution for the data passing.

Comment: Getting a: Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'TableViewController1' from 'ViewController' *const__strong

Comment: plaese, post your `@property` declaration and your `prepareForSegue:sender:`

Comment: @property (nonatomic, weak) TableViewController1 *mainController;
 (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    TableViewController1 *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
    destinationController.mainController = self;
}

Comment: the propery declaration should be `@property (nonatomic,weak) ViewController *mainController;` in fact its type should be the class of the main controller and not the class of the table view controller. And make sure to import the header of the main controller class too.

Comment: I had it as ViewController at first but it gave me an error and a suggestion to change it to UIViewController. Then I also figured I had to import the header but I already did that previously..

Comment: When I add: @property (nonatomic,weak) ViewController *mainController. To the ViewController.H and not the TableViewController1.h I do not get any errors. But thats not the proper way according to your suggestions.

Comment: Could you send me the whole content of your table view controller header file? And please tell me what error you get when using `ViewController` as the type for the property and `import "ViewController.h"`

Comment: #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "ViewController.h"

interface TableViewController1 :  UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
 
 NSArray *tableViewArray;
    
}
property (nonatomic,weak) ViewController *mainController;
property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableViewIndustry;

Comment: Had to remove the '@'s at above comment, it wouldnt let me post otherwise.The error im getting is: Unknown type name 'ViewController' : did you mean 'UIViewController'?

Comment: do you have google talk? solving this is getting long and it seems that you do not have enough reputation to chat on stackoverflow

Comment: torylon123@gmail.com , I hope..haha

Comment: ahah okok I'm sending the request to chat with you go on gmail to accept it!